Proof for $\frac{x}{a} = \frac{y}{b} = \frac{z}{c} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}} $
My teacher used this relation to prove another result, but I can not seem to wrap my head around it.
$\frac{x}{a} = \frac{y}{b} = \frac{z}{c} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}} $
An explanation will be welcomed

Are you sure you're not omitting some information? What even are the assumptions?

HINT : $t=\frac{x}{a} = \frac{y}{b} = \frac{z}{c}  \implies x^2+y^2+z^2=t^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)$

@Keen-ameteur I believe so I am not omitting anything. I have tried putting in a few values for x, y, z, a, b and c and the relations stays intact

I have no idea what's the question here.

What do you mean relations stay intact? If I put in $x = 0$ and $y \neq 0$ then surely $\frac xa \neq \frac yb$.

@JJacquelin Ahh! Yes, now it seems very trivial

Hi, welcome to MSE! This question looks OK but I would advise you to add the work you have done in trying to answer it so that other people can help you and can understand your level of math maturity.

In addition, you should include the context in which this arose.

Given that:
$$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{c}$$
we can say,
$$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{c}=k$$
moving denominators to on side
$$x=ak$$
$$y=bk$$
$$z=ck$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\sqrt{a^2k^2+b^2k^2+c^2k^2}=k\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
making
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=k$$
hence,
$$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{c}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=k$$
This is only true if we know that the initial assumption is true
Edit: As Ennar Commented: If $ x ,y ,z < 0$ and $a ,b ,c > 0$, this will not be true.

If $x,y,z<0$ and $a,b,c>0$, this is obviously not true.

With the help of @JJacquelin hint the explanation is rather trivial.
We assume
$\frac{x}{a} = \frac{y}{b} = \frac{z}{c} = k $
then
$x = ka, y = kb,z = kc$
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = k^2(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)$
$k^2 = \frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$
Therefore,
$\frac{x}{a} = \frac{y}{b} = \frac{z}{c} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}} $

If $x,y,z<0$ and $a,b,c>0$, this is obviously not true. Your question is ill-posed (what even is the question), but you are ignoring the comments about it.

@Ennar I am ignoring them because my doubt has been resolved. I appreciate your time :)

Well, this is nothing personal, but such questions are not appreciated here on MSE. Lazy is the word that comes to mind.

@Ennar I had searched the entire internet to find a proof for this and I couldn't find anything anywhere. I always avoid stackexchange network because my questions always get removed, for such similar reason despite the fact I often see similar lazy doubts staying up on the site. Please note that its not just math phds who find trouble with higher level maths but younger gen as well :)

Your questions don't get removed because they are elementary, but because you actively refuse to communicate with people trying to help you improve the question. When you are asking question, it's not just about you, the question has to be, at least in theory, useful to wider audience, anyone who would have a similar problem in the future. We try to make an archive of questions and answers and preserve it in time. Poor questions pollute this. Your question is not even a proper question, you clearly do not want to prove what it says you want to prove, but you simply don't care to correct it.
